# Adding content via wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm developing a wordpress theme where I have a set of custom pages and each page has it's own content! For an example, say there is a custom page where the content is already done using HTML but I need to be able to change the content of a single paragraph using the wordpress admin panel.

How do i do this using the wordpress framework? is there any special way of adding custom editable fields to specific content locations in a page?

Comment: you can use advance custom field plugin to do so

Comment: Um actually I've got to only deliver the theme without any plugins. Should be able to do it using the core features of wordpress

Comment: Another option is to use visual composer plugin and generate custom short-code with your html this is more relevant way

Comment: you can add custom meta box  , without plugin this is best way ,

Comment: Check this wordpress plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/screenshots/) it should work for you.

Comment: @anubhav could you point me to an example on the custom meta fields implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add meta box and get the values from post meta to show in your html

you can generate metabox from this site without any programing skills

https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/

and get meta field value with the below code

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'meta_key', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php 
    $id=2; 
    $post = get_post($id); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo $content;  
?>
```

Here, $id=2 is your page id which is you get from WordPress Admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wordpress loop to do this:

```
<div class="content">
<p>Your static content goes here</p>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<p>Or here</p>
</div>
```

This part between if(have_posts()) and endif; will be generated from Wordpress admin panel so you can easily change it with page WYSIWYG editor without any additional plugins.

Don't forget to create your custom pages as page templates and assign to page in admin panel otherwise it won't work as expected.